# Make a SmallImage complication with an ambient image

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-complication

I'm trying to make a WearOS Complication that is just an image. Ideally, it should display the image img1.png when on [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNi0C.png), and the image outlines.png when in ambient mode [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5qYB.png).

Right now, I've got

```
return when (request.complicationType) {

        ComplicationType.SMALL_IMAGE -> SmallImageComplicationData.Builder(
            smallImage = SmallImage.Builder(
                Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.img1), SmallImageType.PHOTO).build(),
            contentDescription = PlainComplicationText
                .Builder(text = "Sample text").build()
        )
            .setTapAction(complicationPendingIntent)
            .build()

        else -> {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.WARN)) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unexpected complication type ${request.complicationType}")
            }
            null
        }
    }
```

and I want to add the ambient image somewhere but don't know how. This code sample is inside the `onComplicationRequest` function, which returns `ComplicationData?` by the way. I have the same issue with

```
override fun getPreviewData(type: ComplicationType): ComplicationData {
    return SmallImageComplicationData.Builder(
        smallImage = SmallImage.Builder(
            Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.img1), SmallImageType.PHOTO).build(),
        contentDescription = PlainComplicationText
            .Builder(text = "Your loved one's images!").build()
    )
        .setTapAction(null)
        .build()
}
```

which again, returns `ComplicationData`. Any ideas? Thanks!
(The documentation for WearOS development is pretty incomplete imo :P)

Answer (score 0):

It's on SmallImage.Builder

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/watchface/complications/data/SmallImage.Builder#setAmbientImage(android.graphics.drawable.Icon)

Try

```
        SmallImageComplicationData.Builder(
            smallImage = SmallImage.Builder(
                Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.img1), SmallImageType.PHOTO)
              .setAmbientImage(...)
              .build(),
            contentDescription = PlainComplicationText
                .Builder(text = "Sample text").build()
        )
            .setTapAction(complicationPendingIntent)
            .build()
```